# python: strings in a list to dictionary in a for loop

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary, for-loop

I have a list of text as follows:

```
my_texts = ['apples are available', 'Citrus is beneficial', 'the sky is blue',
            'the grass is green', 'not available', 'not possible']
```

i am analyzing the text in the following for loop and would like to convert the strings to a dictionary.

```
for entry in [entry for entry in my_texts]:
    if len(entry.split()) > 2:
        if entry.split(' ', 1)[0] != 'apples':
           print (dict.fromkeys(entry ,'analyzed'))
```

however the current output is really different from my desired output:

```
 current_output = {'C': 'analyzed', 'i': 'analyzed', 't': 'analyzed', 'r': 'analyzed',   'u': 'analyzed', 's': 'analyzed', ' ': 'analyzed', 'b': 'analyzed', 'e': 'analyzed', 'n': 'analyzed', 'f': 'analyzed', 'c': 'analyzed', 'a': 'analyzed', 'l': 'analyzed'}
                  {'t': 'analyzed', 'h': 'analyzed', 'e': 'analyzed', ' ': 'analyzed', 's': 'analyzed', 'k': 'analyzed', 'y': 'analyzed', 'i': 'analyzed', 'b': 'analyzed', 'l': 'analyzed', 'u': 'analyzed'}
                  {'t': 'analyzed', 'h': 'analyzed', 'e': 'analyzed', ' ': 'analyzed', 'g': 'analyzed', 'r': 'analyzed', 'a': 'analyzed', 's': 'analyzed', 'i': 'analyzed', 'n': 'analyzed'}
```

while my desired output is :

```
desired_output ={'Citrus is beneficial': 'analyzed'}
                {'the sky is blue': 'analyzed'}
                {'the grass is green': 'analyzed'}
```

Comment: `for entry in my_texts` should suffice. The list comprehension isn't serving any purpose here.

Comment: Why `dict.fromkeys`? Just do `{entry: 'analyzed'}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution based on dictionary generator (https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/comprehensions/dict_comprehension.html):

```
print({entry:'analyzed' for entry in my_texts if len(entry.split()) > 2 and entry.split()[0] != 'apples'})
```

**Output:**

```
{'Citrus is beneficial': 'analyzed', 'the sky is blue': 'analyzed', 'the grass is green': 'analyzed'}
```

If you want N dictionaries with 1 element in each, you can use

```
for entry in my_texts:
    if len(entry.split()) > 2 and entry.split()[0] != 'apples':
        print({entry: 'analyzed'})
```

**Output2:**

```
{'Citrus is beneficial': 'analyzed'}
{'the sky is blue': 'analyzed'}
{'the grass is green': 'analyzed'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read about fromkeys() method. The method returns a new dictionary with the given sequence of elements as the keys of the dictionary.

```
seq = "hello"
value = dict.fromkeys(seq, "world")
print(value)
# the output is {'h': 'world', 'e': 'world', 'l': 'world', 'o': 'world'}
```